# 3G Internet stick - which library makes this work

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-device-driver, 3g, gentoo

I have 3G internet stick, [Tele2 Huawei MF190](http://www.tele2.hr/upload/images/Modemi%20fotke/ZTE_MF190_1.png). Now, when I connect it with Ubuntu, Debian etc., it asks me for my PIN and I just choose my provider and everything works great.

Now, when I do the same thing on other Linux distributions (I think it was Arch, Gentoo) it's not working out-of-the-box. Now, what library I actually need to have for this to work?

Why? I'm going to try making my own distro (just-for-learning) from [LinuxFromStratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/) project and I want to be sure to include this library for 3G Internet sticks.

Thank you all! :)

Comment: What sort of troubleshooting have you tried on other distributions?

Comment: None, I really don't know where to start with this problem. I figured out I need some libraries because on Ubuntu and Debian it works out-of-the-box. xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setup **[`usb-modeswitch`](http://www.draisberghof.de/usb_modeswitch/)**.

Couple of general guides explaining how to configure it are available [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Connect-Reliance-Broadband+-Zte-Modem-in-Linux-%28Using-Usb_Modeswitch%29) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43805/help-with-implementing-usb-modeswitch).

Also this **[discussion](http://www.draisberghof.de/usb_modeswitch/bb/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=1298)** explains the exact steps needed to get **Huawei MF190** working on Linux with the help of `usb-modeswitch`.